# I have written below code, I need to change the response like-

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
        {
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);

            using (UserAuthentication objUser = new UserAuthentication())
            {
                //var user = db.ApiUsers.Where(o => o.UserName == context.UserName && o.UserPasswd == context.Password).FirstOrDefault();
                var user = objUser.ValidateUser(context.UserName, context.Password);
                if (user == "false")
                {
                    context.SetError("invalid_grant", "Username or password is incorrect"); 
                    if(context.ErrorDescription == "Username or password is incorrect")
                    {
                        
                    }
                    context.Response.StatusCode = 200;                   
                  
                    return;
                }
                else
                {                   
                    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, context.UserName));
                    await Task.Run(() => context.Validated(identity));
                }
            }
        }
```

Output:
{
"error": "invalid_grant",
"error_description": "Username or password is incorrect"
}

The output should like:
{
"Message": "invalid_grant",
"Message_Description": "Username or password is incorrect"
}

Comment: Why would you want change the validator response?  
This is the standard of OAuth 2.0. Check line 40 of the original class https://github.com/vairam-svs/katana/blob/9c69a9d81f28b79e7f3aa008e98256f9e095fb70/src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth/Provider/BaseValidatingContext.cs#L76

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own formatted class and mapping like this:

```
public class FormattedError
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("Message_Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public static class OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContextExtensions
{
    public static FormattedError ToFormattedError(this OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        return new FormattedError()
        {
            Message = context.Error,
            Description = context.ErrorDescription,
        };
    }
}
```

And in a place where you a have context with error you can get formatted error:

```
var formattedError = context.ToFormattedError();
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Dmytro Krivoruchenko is not good enough.

The error object is serialized in the class 'OAuthAuthorizationServerHandler.cs' [git file line 716](https://github.com/vairam-svs/katana/blob/9c69a9d81f28b79e7f3aa008e98256f9e095fb70/src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth/OAuthAuthorizationServerHandler.cs#L716).

The constants present in the 'OAuthConstants.cs' class are used for serialization. [git file line 21](https://github.com/vairam-svs/katana/blob/9c69a9d81f28b79e7f3aa008e98256f9e095fb70/src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth/OAuthConstants.cs#L21).

You would have to create your own Authorization Handler to be able to modify the error response.